# Seeking references and advice for modeling time series data in Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm new to MonogoEngine and web apps in general and I've got programmers block.  I'd like to create a model(s) for logging periodic recorded values from equipment.  Based on a [MongoDB blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb), I'm going for something like the following (copy/pasted from their post):

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    0: { 0: 999999, 1: 999999, …, 59: 1000000 },
    1: { 0: 2000000, 1: 2000000, …, 59: 1000000 },
    …,
    58: { 0: 1600000, 1: 1200000, …, 59: 1100000 },
    59: { 0: 1300000, 1: 1400000, …, 59: 1500000 }
  }
}
```

I'd like the document to be more along the lines of the following for a data point logged each minute for one day for multiple values.

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
  equipmentID: “123456”,
  parameter1: {
    0: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null },
    1: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null },
    …,
    22: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null },
    23: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null }
  },
  parameter2: {
    0: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null },
    1: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null },
    …,
    22: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null },
    23: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null }
  }
}
```

So, my trouble is how to set this up as model(s).

1. I was thinking "0: { 0: null, 1: null, …, 59: null }" is a model of embeddedDocument type.  Then add these to the a model of Parameters.  Is that the right path?
2. The number of parameters may vary, so maybe these need to be as part of a listField?
3. Can an embeddedDocument be embedded in an EmbeddedDocument?

Comment: Answer to 3:  Yes, embeddedDocument can be embedded in an EmbeddedDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the benefits of using MongoEngine in this case would be over pymongo directly.  It might be cumbersome for such a large model - where as interacting with a dictionary of a known schema in my mind would be simpler.

So this all comes with a caveat and warning - it can be done in MongoEngine, I'm just not sure its your best course of action for a happy experience.

1. It would be a nested EmbeddedDocument eg:

   ```
   class SecondAggreate(EmbeddedDocument):
       s0 = IntField()
       s1 = IntField()
       ...
       s59 = IntField()

   class MinuteAggregate(EmbeddedDocument):
       m0 = EmbeddedDocumentField(SecondAggregate)
       m1 = EmbeddedDocumentField(SecondAggregate)
       ...
       m59 = EmbeddedDocumentField(SecondAggregate)
   ```

   Notice we have to add a `m` or `s` to the keys denoting minutes and seconds because we can't have attributes that are literals. Use `db_field_name` to ensure you don't store that extra data.
2. In the example the fields are fixed, they aren't required so you don't have to store them - but the types are defined for when you do. You could use a list but there are other considerations for lists but its simpler with a dictionary as you define the key.
3. Yes - see point 1.

Final caveat - if you choose to do this in MongoEngine (and as shown above you can) then don't use `Doc.save()` make sure any updates are explicit as `save()` may introduce race conditions if multiple threads try and update the document at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Ross for the response.  Last night I played around with pymongo directly because I could easily get the dictionary to be exactly as I wanted where as in MongoEngine it was a bit cumbersome.  Thanks for the help and tips about save.  For this data set, I think I'll stick with pymongo as the nesting and naming of each key is easier too.